# How do I iterate inside a subarray and the retrieve the key and value in jolt transformation?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a json input which has few arrays inside an array . How do I loop inside the subarrays and get the key and values of all the data in subarrays in output?

this is the JSON **input** :

```json
{
  "Groups": [],
  "Instances": [
    {
      "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
      "Architecture": "x86_64",
      "BlockDeviceMappings": [
        {
          "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
          "Ebs": {
            "AttachTime": "2020-08-14 05:59:12+00:00",
            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
            "Status": "attached",
            "VolumeId": "vol-032e47441"
          }
        },
        {
          "DeviceName": "xvdf",
          "Ebs": {
            "AttachTime": "2020-08-28 11:33:",
            "DeleteOnTermination": false,
            "Status": "attached",
            "VolumeId": "vol-0f7b6c9"
          }
        }
      ],
      "CapacityReservationSpecification": {
        "CapacityReservationPreference": "open"
      },
      "ClientToken": "",
      "CpuOptions": {
        "CoreCount": 1,
        "ThreadsPerCore": 1
      },
      "EbsOptimized": false,
      "EnaSupport": true,
      "EnclaveOptions": {
        "Enabled": false
      },
      "HibernationOptions": {
        "Configured": false
      },
      "Hypervisor": "abc",
      "ImageId": "ami-040be",
      "InstanceId": "i-0a19747c",
      "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
      "KeyName": "MyClan",
      "LaunchTime": "2023-03-13 ",
      "MaintenanceOptions": {
        "AutoRecovery": "default"
      },
      "MetadataOptions": {
        "HttpEndpoint": "enabled",
        "HttpProtocolIpv6": "disabled",
        "HttpPutResponseHopLimit": 1,
        "HttpTokens": "optional",
        "InstanceMetadataTags": "disabled",
        "State": "applied"
      },
      "Monitoring": {
        "State": "enabled"
      },
      "NetworkInterfaces": [
        {
          "Attachment": {
            "AttachTime": "2020-08-14 05:59:",
            "AttachmentId": "eni-attach-ecfb56",
            "DeleteOnTermination": true,
            "DeviceIndex": 0,
            "NetworkCardIndex": 0,
            "Status": "attached"
          },
          "Description": "",
          "Groups": [
            {
              "GroupId": "sg-0d947",
              "GroupName": "bc"
            }
          ],
          "InterfaceType": "interface",
          "Ipv6Addresses": [],
          "MacAddress": "12:36:47:bf:7a:0b",
          "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-0893e4f6",
          "OwnerId": "01611",
          "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-87.ec2.internal",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "10.87",
          "PrivateIpAddresses": [
            {
              "Primary": true,
              "PrivateDnsName": "ip1-87.ec2.internal",
              "PrivateIpAddress": "10.87"
            },
            {
              "Primary": false,
              "PrivateDnsName": "ip-48.ec2.internal",
              "PrivateIpAddress": "10.48"
            }
          ],
          "SourceDestCheck": true,
          "Status": "in-use",
          "SubnetId": "subnet-0b457b34d",
          "VpcId": "vpc-05cc8"
        }
      ],
      "Placement": {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-south-3b",
        "GroupName": "",
        "Tenancy": "default"
      },
      "PlatformDetails": "abc",
      "PrivateDnsName": "ip87.ec2.internal",
      "PrivateDnsNameOptions": {},
      "PrivateIpAddress": "10.7.9.87",
      "ProductCodes": [],
      "PublicDnsName": "",
      "RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
      "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
      "SecurityGroups": [
        {
          "GroupId": "sg-0d975c747",
          "GroupName": "Bnm"
        }
      ],
      "SourceDestCheck": true,
      "State": {
        "Code": 16,
        "Name": "running"
      },
      "StateTransitionReason": "",
      "SubnetId": "subnet-0b234d",
      "Tags": [
        {
          "Key": "MakeSnapshot",
          "Value": "true"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Owner",
          "Value": "Amitdw"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Expiry Date",
          "Value": "12-Jun-2024"
        },
        {
          "Key": "vmname",
          "Value": "i-0a7b19747c"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Name",
          "Value": "fcva"
        },
        {
          "Key": "Purpose",
          "Value": "Performance Data"
        }
      ],
      "UsageOperation": "RunInstances:00",
      "UsageOperationUpdateTime": "2020-08-14 05:59:11+00:00",
      "VirtualizationType": "hvm",
      "VpcId": "vpc-058dcc8"
    }
  ],
  "OwnerId": "0161",
  "ReservationId": "r-02469ebf"
}
```

**My spec** :

I have tried to loop in the first array and got the 2 keys and values in the output , I am unable to enter the subarray even after mentioning the array name and * operation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Instances": {
        "*": {
          "AmiLaunchIndex": "[&1].AmiLaunchIndex",
          "Architecture": "[&1].Architecture"
        }
      },
      "BlockDeviceMappings": {
        "*": {
          "DeviceName": "[&1].DeviceName"
        }
      },
      "Ebs": {
        "*": {
          "AttachTime": "[&1].AttachTime",
          "DeleteOnTermination": "[&1].DeleteOnTermination",
          "Status": "[&1].Status",
          "VolumeId": "[&1].VolumeId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**My output** :

( *The output is limited only to the first array , it is not iterating the subarrays which were looped in the code* )

```json
[
 {
   "AmiLaunchIndex" : 0,
   "Architecture" : "x86_64"
 }
]
```

It is not looping past the first array.There are multiple arrays and subarrays in the json input. How do I iterate the arrays in the shift operation and get the correct key and values in the required output

**required output** :

```json
[
{
"ReservationId":"r-00347618e087e",

 

"OwnerId":"016702611",

 

"GroupSet:"",

 

"InstancesSet_item_instanceId":"i-0560ce5b0",

 

"InstancesSet_item_ImageId":"ami-0ea6a9ded".

 

"InstancesSet_Item_InstanceState_code":"80",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_InstanceState_name":"stopped",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_PrivateDnsName":["ip-10-7-20.internal","ip-10-7-20.internal".....],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_DnsName":["ip-10-7-20.internal","ip-10-7-20.internal"......],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Reason":"",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_KeyName":"ashok",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_AmiLaunchIndex":"0",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_ProductCodes":[],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_InstanceType":"t2.medium",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_LaunchTime":"2023-07-17 06:31:04+00:00",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Placement_AvailabilityZone":"us-east-1c",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Placement_GroupName":"default",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Placement_Tenancy":"default",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Monitoring_State:"disabled",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_SubnetId": "subnet-0d19137b8e40",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_VpcId":"vpc-054781249cc8",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_PrivateIpAddress":"10.7.20.257",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_SourceDestCheck": "true",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_GroupSet_Item_GroupId":"sg-015e76c6239b"

 

"InstancesSet_Item_GroupSet_Item_GroupName":"default",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Architecture:"x86_64",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_RootDeviceType":"eb",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_RootDeviceName": "/dev/sda1",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_VirtualizationType":"hvm",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_ClientToken":"7d9e6e89-89ba-4b9865b0f8796",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Hypervisor":"xen",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceId":"eni-0481a1b15f",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_SubnetId":"subnet-0d19137af7,

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_VpcId":"vpc-054781249208",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Description":"",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_OwnerId":"01670611",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Status":"in-use",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_MacAddress":"0e:a5:d9:b1:5f",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_PrivateIpAddress":"10.7.247",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_PrivateDnsName":"ip-10-7-247.ec2.internal",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_SourceDestCheck":"true",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_GroupSet_Item_GroupId":"sg-015eb6239b",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_GroupSet_Item_GroupName":"default",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Attachment_AttachmentId":"eni-attach-085ab400ca0a"

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Attachment_DeviceIndex":"0",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Attachment_Status":"attached",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Attachment_AttachTime":"2023-07-13 06:51:15+00:00",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Attachment_DeleteOnTermination":"true",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Attachment_NetworkCardIndex":"0",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_Ipv6AddressesSet":"[ ]",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_InterfaceType":"interface",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_EbsOptimized:"false",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_EnaSupport":"true",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_CpuOptions_CoreCount:"2",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_CpuOptions_ThreadsPerCore:"1",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_CapacityReservationSpecification_CapacityReservationPreference:"open",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_HibernationOptions_Configured:"false",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_EnclaveOptions_Enabled":"false",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_metadataOptions_State":"applied",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_metadataOptions_HttpTokens":"optional",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_metadataOptions_HttpPutResponseHopLimit":"1",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_metadataOptions_HttpEndpoint":"enabled",

 

"InstancesSet_TagSet_Key":["name","purpose"],

 

"InstancesSet_TagSet_value":["test1","Disk"],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_Platform":"windows",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_StateReason_Code": "Client.UserInitiatedShutdown",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_StateReason_Message":"Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_BootMode":"legacy-bios",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_BlockDeviceMapping_Item_DeviceName":["/dev/sda1", "xvdf","xvdg","xvdh"],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_BlockDeviceMapping_Item_Ebs_VolumeId":["vol-0df9d3b259d7c3","vol-0b037b1913568c","vol-09a1c38ef279e","vol-0786e6c0889ebb"],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_BlockDeviceMapping_Item_Ebs_Status":["attached","attached","attached"],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_BlockDeviceMapping_Item_Ebs_AttachTime":["2023-07-14 12:10:22+00:00","2023-07-14 12:10:40+00:00","2023-07-14 12:10:51+00:00"],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_BlockDeviceMapping_Item_ebs_deleteOnTermination":["true","false","false","false"],

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_PrivateIpAddressesSet_Item_PrivateIpAddress:"10.7.247",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_PrivateIpAddressesSet_Item_PrivateDnsName":"ip-10-7-247.ec2.internal",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_NetworkInterfaceSet_Item_PrivateIpAddressesSet_Item_Primary":"true",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_IamInstanceProfile_Arn":""arn:aws:iam::01672611:instance-profile/SSMaccess",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_IamInstanceProfile_Id":"AIPAQHYOHUOY",
 

"CustomerName":"",

 

"ServiceName":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_platformDetails":"Windows",

 

"instancesSet_item_usageOperation":"RunInstances:0002",

 

"InstancesSet_Item_TagSet_Item":"",

 

"CustomerDisplayName":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_instanceState":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_placement":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_monitoring":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_ipAddress":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_groupSet":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_blockDeviceMapping":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_tagSet":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_networkInterfaceSet":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_iamInstanceProfile":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_cpuOptions":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_capacityReservationSpecification":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_hibernationOptions":"",
 

"instancesSet_item_enclaveOptions":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_metadataOptions":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_maintenanceOptions":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_usageOperationUpdateTime":"",
 

"instancesSet_item_privateDnsNameOptions":"",

 

"requesterId":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_stateReason":"",

 

"instancesSet_item_currentInstanceBootMode":"",

 

"EngagementId":"",

 

"Sign":""

 

"Version":"1"
}
]
```

Comment: Do you want to return the first returning values among duplicated attributes during flattening. Btw, some values from the input and the required output don't match.

Comment: I want the keys and values from from each array to be returned in the output(among the duplicated attributes), and yes I have changed the values in the input and output because some of it is sensitive information

Comment: As an example : `"VolumeId" : [ "vol-032e47441", "vol-0f7b6c9" ]` returns, which one do you wanna pick up, the first? Does `"VolumeId": "vol-032e4776"` ,  which doesn't exist within the input ,really should be returned. If they're sensitive, then none of them should be unveiled, ain't it?

Comment: hii, I need all the volumeIds from all the arrays and subarrays in one single output array. for example :"VolumeId" : [ "vol-032e47441", "vol-0f7b6c9" ,"vol-09a1c3.....etc"] ,"AttachTime":["2020-08-14 05:59:",......etc"] , and similarly all the keys which are there in the subarrays should print their values in similar array format in output . I have modified the values to an extent that they are not sensitive anymore . Kindly help me with the jolt spec . Thank you

Comment: Well but question has not been edited yet.

Comment: sorry for the confusion barbaros , I have edited the required output . If there are any keys in the output which are not present in the input json kindly leave them with empty value (""}. Please help me out here,Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "Instances": {
    "*": {
      "AmiLaunchIndex": "[&1].AmiLaunchIndex",
      "Architecture": "[&1].Architecture",
      "BlockDeviceMappings": {
        "*": {
          "DeviceName": "[&3].DeviceName",
          "Ebs": {
            "AttachTime": "[&4].AttachTime",
            "DeleteOnTermination": "[&4].DeleteOnTermination",
            "Status": "[&4].Status",
            "VolumeId": "[&4].VolumeId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
]
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[ {
"AmiLaunchIndex" : 0,
"Architecture" : "x86_64",
"DeviceName" : [ "/dev/sda1", "xvdf" ],
"AttachTime" : [ "2020-08-14 05:59:12+00:00", "2020-08-28 11:33:" ],
"DeleteOnTermination" : [ true, false ],
"Status" : [ "attached", "attached" ],
"VolumeId" : [ "vol-032e47441", "vol-0f7b6c9" ]
} ]
```